# excel formula to find non repeated values from two different columns or more

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Each code from *A column* has a defined value in the *B column* (B1 to A1, B2 to A2, etc.). The same for *D* and *E columns*.
I'd like a formula that gives me all the values related to a determined code that i put on cell F1, with non repeated values (i need unique values), as shown in *G column*.

I´ve tried with thousand variations of this formula,

{=INDEX(B:B;SMALL(IF(A:A=$F$1;ROW());ROW()))}

The best I could do was only to get results just from one column, and with repeated values, as shown in the *I Column*

Here is a photo for guidance

[image: Example]

I'll apreciate some help

Comment: I would probably use what you have in column I to get what's needed in column G. I don't think you can directly get the result you want in column G with formulas alone.

Comment: You can solve this easily with VBA and a Dictionary object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would definately need service columns to the left of the "i" column that would contain the nex formula

(formula next to the left of the "i" column):
**`=if(countif(i$1:i1;i1)=1;row();"---")`**

(formula next to the left of the above formula):
**`=iferror(rank(H1;H;1);"---")`**

then you will need a numerated column from 1 to max possible entries of the values, and a VLOOKUP function to get your unique values:
**`=vlookup(your_enumerated_cell;G:I;3;false)`**

and your done getting unique values from the dataset